# Sort specific table data as date, but rest as text in DataTables

Tags: jquery, date, html-table, datatables

I am using DataTables to sort my tables, but the problem is that it is sorting the "Date" table as text, and i need on specific table data to be sorted as date and the rest as plain text.

I've tried a few example as per their website, but can't find an example that fixed my specific issue. I've tried searching here, but couldn't find anything that would help me.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
 jQuery('#table-sort').DataTable(); 
} );
```

```html
<table id="test" class="table table-striped bid-table">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td><a href="#" class="bid-bulk-mark">Markér samtlige</a></td>
                    <td>Dato</td>
                    <td>Type</td>
                    <td>Tappested</td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                @foreach ($messages as $message)
                    <tr {{ $message->read ? '' : 'class=msg-unread' }}>
                        <td class="msg-icon">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="msg-checkbox[]" class="msg-checkbox" value="{{ $message->id }}">
                            {!! $message->read ? '' : '&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>' !!}
                        </td>
                        <td>{{ $message->date }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $message->type }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $message->place_name }}</td>
                        <td>
 <a href="{{ route('messages.show', $message->id) }}"><i class="fa fa-pencil fa-fw"></i> Vis</a><br>
  <a href="{{ route('messages.destroy', $message->id) }}" data-method="delete" data-csrf="{{ csrf_token() }}" data-confirm="Er du sikker på, at meddelelsen skal arkiveres? Handlingen kan ikke fortrydes."><i class="fa fa-trash fa-fw"></i> Arkivér</a>
      </td>
     </tr>
     @endforeach
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I hope that I can get "Dato" the second TD to sort after date. The date format is 22-08-2019 08:35

So D/M/Y/TIME

Comment: I usually strongly suggest **NOT TO** prepare table HTML (DataTables can perfectly do that on its own). Howerver, you may append `data-sort` attribute containing numeric values of the dates (that can be sorted lexically) to your `<td>`, as suggested [here](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/html5-data-attributes).

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov Thank you a lot for your response. I am not quite sure what you mean by append data-sort attribute. I've looked at the example you've send, and the data-sort attribute just contains the same as the field. Can you make an example to my code? Thx a lot :-D

Comment: Your code is not that readable to me (Danish is none of my strengths) and it has large parts of backend scripting (Laravel or whatever it is), so I can't post relevant live snippet. The major idea is to convert `D/M/Y/TIME` into numeric value (e.g. '22/08/2019 10:41' -> '1566459678371') and generate table cells HTML (for the date column) as `<td data-sort="1566459678371">22/08/2019 10:41</td>`

Comment: ...just in case you might be puzzled as of how to convert date to number, following [function](https://www.php.net/strtotime) might be of use (if I correctly identified your back end language, of course)